# Why is bibtex8 exit status different from bibtex

Tags: bibtex

I'm using a command chain to process my latex files of the form:

```
pdflatex file && bibtex file && pdflatex file && pdflatex file
```

While this works perfectly fine with `bibtex`, when I use `bibtex8` instead the chain stops right after the `bibtex8 file` command. In fact, the exit code of the `bibtex8` command is `1` while for `bibtex` it is `0`, although the processing concludes succesfull with no errors and the produced `file.bbl` files are identical. 
Either `bibtex` either `bibtex8` produce two warnings:

```
bibtex file
The top-level auxiliary file: ERSEM-release.aux
The style file: copernicus.bst
Database file #1: ../bibtex-db/bibtex-db.bib
Database file #2: ../bibtex-db/me.bib
Database file #3: ../bibtex-db/misc.bib
Warning--empty booktitle in falkowski_primary_1992
Warning--missing institution in dickson_guide_2007
(There were 2 warnings)
echo $?
0
```

and correspondingly:

```
bibtex8 file
The 8-bit codepage and sorting file: 88591lat.csf
The top-level auxiliary file: ERSEM-release.aux
The style file: copernicus.bst
Database file #1: ../bibtex-db/bibtex-db.bib
Database file #2: ../bibtex-db/me.bib
Database file #3: ../bibtex-db/misc.bib
Warning--empty booktitle in falkowski_primary_1992
Warning--missing institution in dickson_guide_2007
(There were 2 warnings)
echo $?
1
```

Any suggestions why the two exit codes would be different and how I could change this behaviour?